# SQL NOT EXIST subquery

Tags: sql

I have a situation when I have a number of unique site/primary records with child records, and subsequent grandchild records. I am looking to modify my SQL query so it will populate the unique primary records based on whether or not grandchild records exist, but then further filter down those primary records based on the child record columns.

E.g.

```sql
SELECT PrimaryTable.SiteKey
FROM PrimaryTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT*
    FROM PrimaryTable, ChildTable, GrandChildTable
    WHERE PrimaryTable.SiteKey = ChildTable.SiteKey
    and Childtable.Key = GrandChildTable.ParentKey)
```

This works, whereby the list of sites/primary records that have child records, which do not have grandchild records populate.

If I want to further filter on the Primary table, to the end of the query I could add `AND PrimaryTable.Column1 = 'MyDesiredValue'` and it works fine.
However, I want to filter it by `ChildTable.Column != 'MyDesiredValue'`.

When I do this, I get an error that the parameter is not bound, and the `ChildTable` is not listed at the beginning of the query.

I need the Primary Keys to populate and I cannot use joins using the interface/software I am working with, unfortunately. Hoping there is a way to modify the query above to make it work.

Comment: `I cannot use joins using the interface/software I am working with` This is your main problem. Fix the client software first, then you can use a normal `JOIN` to query, which happens to be one of the most common operations in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

FIrst, convert your query to use an outer (ie LEFT) join, that filters out rows with no grand children. Then add your filter to the join:

```
SELECT distinct PrimaryTable.SiteKey -- distinct, or it'll repeat every join
FROM PrimaryTable
JOIN ChildTable on PrimaryTable.SiteKey = ChildTable.SiteKey -- inner (required) join
    AND ChildTable.Column != 'MyDesiredValue'
LEFT JOIN GrandChildTable on Childtable.Key = GrandChildTable.ParentKey
    AND GrandChildTable.year = 2020
WHERE GrandChildTable.ParentKey IS NULL -- only rows without grandchildren
```

Comment: You can do it with a `not exists` but it's ugly imho and doesn't perform as well (unless the optimizer converts the subquery to my query, which it should but sometimes doesn't).

Comment: It turns out join does work in the interface! Would it be possible to further modify the the query so it does not populate records where a grandchild record is present meeting specific criteria - e.g. I want to populate all instances where the grandchild record does not exist, as well as instances where a grandchild record is present, but it does not have a year value of 2020.

Comment: Yes: see `AND GrandChildTable.year = 2020` in edited answer. You add the condition to the *join*. This point is critical, you can't add it to the `WHERE` clause, otherwise it effectively converts the left join to an inner join, whichstops the query working as desired. Conditions in the join and evaluated *before* the `WHERE` clause is executed, as the join is made.

Comment: Perfect - it works. Absolutely incredible responses.